# React Native alignItems is not working properly in the View

Tags: reactjs, react-native

As you see the picture attached, I set the align item as **center** with the icon and text. However, I do not know why the icon is not aligned. Do you have any idea?

```
...
                <View style={styles.nameElement}>
                  <TouchableOpacity>
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons name="calendar" size={26} />
                    <Text>Calendar</Text>
                    {/* <MaterialCommunityIcons name="calendar-alert" size={26} /> */}
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
...
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
...
  nameElement: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
...
})
```

[image: As you see]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you only set the `alignItem` and `justifyContent` style for the `<View>` component which is not your icon and text container in your case.

So your must set `<TouchableOpacity style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<View style={styles.nameElement}>
  <TouchableOpacity style={{alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",}}>
    <MaterialCommunityIcons name="calendar" size={26} />
    <Text>Calendar</Text>
    {/* <MaterialCommunityIcons name="calendar-alert" size={26} /> */}
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```